# SDL2 Vsynced renderer and physics at custom interval - is there a need for separate threads?

Tags: c++, game-physics, sdl-2

I'm playing with making a simple game in C++ and SDL2. I ran into the challenge of having physics run independently of frame rate.

I would like the physics to run at 10ms intervals while using vsync for rendering (if I don't use vsync, there's screen tear with manual capping).

The issue is that the render function (SDL_RENDER_PRESENT) with vsync will block the loop (the call will take enough time to maintain the fps). Is my understanding correct that the only way to have physics run at a higher frequency than screen refresh rate while using vsync, is to use separate threads?

I saw this article for instance with some great tips on how to run physics at fixed interval: https://gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/ - however, it appears it's all on a single thread. Perhaps the author is using a different rendering library where render() method doesn't block?

So again my question is, if I use SDL2 and I want vsync, there's pretty much no other way to custom-interval physics than using separate threads?

Comment: I don't understand the problem, the article you linked actually tells you how to do what you want to do.

Comment: Ok. I think I get it. I thought that in order to run physics at 10ms intervals, it would have to be literally 10ms intervals - which didn't make sense to me, since render() function blocks 16ms, how can I have 10ms intervals. But it seems like it's about running physics at 10ms intervals on average, while using the 16ms frame step? So in this case, some frames would run physics twice to make up for this ms lost.

Comment: can't you use chrono and just do the physics based off time?